# problem using .split() method in a function but it works on console.log

Tags: javascript, string, methods

the problem is only in the bottom function `objectPutter`
specifically the line with `wowza.split(' ');` labelled with the comment

```js
let eq
let x = null
let bracketNum = 0
let k = 0
let pre = 0

class subEqCreator { //subEq object
  constructor() {
    this.precede = 0;
    this.text = '';
  }
  parser() {
    this.text += eq[k]
  }
  ma() {
    this.text.split(' ')
  }
};

function trigger() { //used for HTML onClick method
  show();
  brackets();
  subEqDynamic()
  parseEquation();
  objectPutter()
};

function show() {
  const recent = document.querySelector("ol");
  const txt = document.getElementById('input');
  eq = txt.value;
  li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = eq;
  recent.appendChild(li);
  txt.value = '';
};

function brackets() { //counts how many brackets appear
  for (let i = 0; i < eq.length; i++) {
    if (eq[i] == "(") {
      bracketNum++;
    };
  };
};
let subEqDynamic = function() { // creates a new object for each bracket
  for (let count = 0; count <= bracketNum; count++) {
    this['subEq' + count] = x = new subEqCreator()
  };
};

function parseEquation() { // assign characters to SubEq object
  let nextIndex = 0;
  let currentIndex = 0;
  let lastIndex = [0];
  let eqLen = eq.length;
  let nex = this['subEq' + nextIndex]

  for (k; k < eqLen; k++) {
    if (eq[k] == "(") {
      nextIndex++;
      pre++
      this['subEq' + currentIndex].text += '( )';
      this['subEq' + nextIndex].precede = pre;
      lastIndex.push(currentIndex);
      currentIndex = nextIndex;
    } else if (eq[k] == ")") {
      pre--
      currentIndex = lastIndex.pop();
    } else {
      this['subEq' + currentIndex].parser()
    }
  }
}


function objectPutter() {
  for (let i = 0; i < bracketNum; i++) {
    let wowza = this['subEq' + i].text
    wowza.split(' '); //   why isnt it working here 
    console.log(subEq0);
    for (let j = 1; j <= wowza.length; j += 2) { // for loop generates only odds
      let ni = i++
        wowza.splice(j, 0, this['subEq' + ni])
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}
```

to fix this i tried;

1. making a method for it `ma()` in the constructor.
2. putting in the function `parseEquation` above in case it was a scope issue.

also, i noticed `subEq0.split(' ')` worked in  browser console even replicating it to the way i done it using `this['subEq' + i].text.split(' ')` where `i = 0`.

After it runs the it says `.splice` is not a function and `console.log(subEq0)` shows `subEq0.text` is still a string

Comment: `this` in `objectPutter` is not what you think it is when calling the function like you've called it (`objectPutter()` ).

Comment: You're using `this` in a number of functions that aren't object methods. Outside a method, `this` defaults to the `window` object.

Comment: It should be `wowza = wowza.split(' ')` (but using a new variable would be better)

Comment: Also, subEq0.text will always stay a string, unless you assign the result to it as well.

Answer (score 3):

.split() does not change the variable it returns the splitted variable